# How do I check if a server is using an ECDSA fingerprint in SSH otherwise quit?

Tags: ssh, tcl, expect, ecdsa

How do I make my expect script check if a server is using an ECDSA key and if it is continue with the script otherwise if it's something like RSA quit immediately?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

#Usage sshsudologin.expect <host> <ssh user> <ssh password>

set timeout 60

spawn ssh [lindex $argv 1]@[lindex $argv 0]

 expect "yes/no" {
     send "yes\r"
     expect "*?assword" { send "[lindex $argv 2]\r" }
    } "*?assword" { send "[lindex $argv 2]\r" }

 expect " " { send "sudo su -\r" }
 expect " " { send "commands\r" }
 expect " " { send "exit\r" }
 expect " " { send "exit\r" }
 interact
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simplest to just configure the client to only support ECDSA keys on that particular connection prior to attempting to connect?

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the Donal's comment, you seem to want to override the `HostKeyAlgorithms` client's configuration variable on the command line (or by other means) when connecting as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/217066).  If you only specify ECDSA mechanisms, the connection will supposedly fail, if the server only will only offer you an RSA-, DSA- or FIPS-based key.